# How to implement google maps in my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I am totally confused with google maps and maps of iPhone...

i have read that iPhone uses google maps.....and also spent some time on it....

But it never display the items like  location pictures, balloons etc.

---

**EDIT**

**THIS is photo for of browser** [image]

**and following is same place for iPhone maps**[image]

second one did not show the annotation added by people.....
(this is what i was asking for ballons or other pictures which people adds to location  on oogle maps)

---

I want to display all those in my application....

what should i do...

if you suggests implement Google maps API, then please suggest a working link...or provide some sample code if possible.....if anybody has done it...then please mail me at yogeshkumau@gmail.com

waiting for answer......

Answer (score 2):

Points of Interests(location, pictures and baloons) that you are talking about can be shown in your maps, if you acquire the license for [Google maps premier api](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html). In that case you'd have to use dynamic maps by using google's web services. However if you want to implement it using MapKit framework on iOS devices, you'd have to draw your custom POIs using core graphics.

Comment: i know that how to mark a position with a pin or any other item but want to show my maps same as the appear on webView(as you suggested the link).....will google charge me for that?

Comment: I don't think there wld be any problems, untill and unless you follow the geocoder limits. Refer http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#geocoder_limit

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a special agreement with Google to use their maps on their platform. The internet is packed with examples of usage of MKMapView along with annotations (pins, there're no baloons on iPhone).

Comment: i don't see any clarification in your post whatsoever!

Comment: i am talking about map on MKMapView exactly same as they look on an webView...(except those more options like make apoint and some other editing options)